# Are Centaurs really "part-human"?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* Hermione says following:

> 'You mark my words, she's going to want revenge on Dumbledore for appointing a new teacher without consulting her,' said Hermione, closing the newspaper. 'Especially another part-human. You saw the look on her face when she saw Firenze.'

So Hermione thinks that the Centaurs are "part-human". Still Firenze thinks otherwise:

> 'Centaurs are not the servants or playthings of humans,' said Firenze
>   quietly.

Or at least it sounds that the Centaurs will be very insulted if they are called "part-human".

So are they really part-human or a separate species?

Comment: Literally part-human. As is the British way, the wizards try to ignore the implications.

Comment: Does that quote from Firenze REALLY contradict the part-human description, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Centaurs are a distinct species from humans, but share some physical attributes.

Most of the information we have on Centaurs can be found in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them

The most clear example of a distinction between centaurs and humans that I can find is in the following line.

> Wizarding authorities in each of the countries where centaurs are found have allocated areas where the centaurs will not be troubled by Muggles; **however, centaurs stand in little need of wizard protection, having their own means
>   of hiding from humans.**
>   <sub>(*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them - Centaurs*)</sub>

Centaurs differ than Humans in many ways:

- **Physically**

  > The centaur has a human head, torso, and arms joined to a horse’s body which may be any of several colours.
  >   <sub>(*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them - Centaurs*)</sub>
- **Mentally**

  > The centaurs’ habits are not humanlike; they live in the wild, refuse clothing, prefer to live apart from wizards and Muggles alike.
  >   <sub>(*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them - Inroduction - What is a Beast?*)</sub>
- **Legally**

  > Being intelligent and capable of speech, it should not strictly speaking be termed a beast, but by its own request it has been classified as such by the Ministry of Magic.
  >   <sub>(*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them - Centaurs*)</sub>

While it is technically possible that they originated from humans way back when, we would have nothing to back it on. The fact that they share a resemblance to humans isn't that unusual, as many magical beasts look part human. (e.g. Merpeople, sphinxes, veela, Dukuwaqa, etc.) What we *do know* about the origin of Centaurs was that they (most probably) came from Greece.

> Centaurs are believed to have originated in Greece, though there are now centaur communities in many parts of Europe.
>   <sub>(*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them - Centaurs*)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

### Uncertain.

Centaurs such as Bane (who could be categorised as deeply "anti-wizard") certainly seem to instantly dismiss any suggestion that they're related to humans. Whether this is simply an example of their own prejudice is unclear.

> ‘That’s right!’ said Umbridge, in an even higher voice, ‘so be very careful! By the laws laid down by the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures, **any attack by half-breeds such as yourselves on a human –’**
>   **‘What did you call us?’ shouted a wild-looking black centaur, whom Harry recognised as Bane.** There was a great deal of angry muttering and tightening of bowstrings around them.
>   ‘Don’t call them that!’ Hermione said furiously, - <sub><sup>[HP:OotP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Order_of_the_Phoenix)</sup></sub>

and

> ‘We do not help humans!’ snarled the centaur holding Harry, tightening his grip and rearing a little at the same time, so that Harry’s feet left the ground momentarily. **‘We are a race apart and proud to be so.** We will not permit you to walk from here, boasting that we did your bidding!’ - <sub><sup>[HP:OotP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Order_of_the_Phoenix)</sup></sub>

---

On the flipside, the factbook "[Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them)" specifically states that ...

> The centaur has **a human head, torso, and arms** joined to a horse’s body
>   which may be any of several colours.

If we take this at its word (e.g. that the top half is actually human) it's hard to imagine how such a creature could have come about without some kind of magical intervention that involved horses and human.

Comment: The centaurs may find it hard to imagine how a human could come about without some kind of magical intervention that involved centaurs and bonobos.

Comment: @MobyDisk - It sounds like you're planning a *very specific* adult slashfic.